# How can I get the product list on header?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

Hi I'm trying to do my first module.

I need to get a copy or the same $products array when I'm located on category page.

I have this code.

```
public function hookHeader($params)
{

    if ('category' == $this->context->controller->php_self){

    $products = //Here I need the same products array from this category

    $this->smarty->assign('products', $products);
    }

    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'views/templates/hook/header.tpl');
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$category = new Category (Tools::getValue('id_category'):
$products = $category->getProducts($this->context->lang->id, 0 99);
```

This will grab 99 products out of the category.

Why can't you 'copy' the category's products? SImply because they have not been assigned yet when you call hookHeader, as the CategoryController comes after that

Also, be aware that will display content in the  portion, and if you want to show anything you must use hookDisplayTop

Also, in 1.6 you should use $this->context->smarty :)

Comment: Thanks Nemo for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Check if the list is already available in smarty array: `error_log(print_r($this->smarty,1));`
2. Use a cateogry-page specific hook that already passes product array to you (it depends on what you need to do). If you need to add something to header, that this is probably the only hook for you. Otherwise, go to `Hook.php` find `exec(` method, add `error_log($hook_name)` and see whcih hooks are executed when you open category page. There may be a hook that will suit your needs.
3. Use a static `Product::` or `Category::` function to grab all the products yourself.